# Spartacus 3.3 - Best approach to start customizing pages and components

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have good knowledge of Angular but I am new to Spartacus storefront.

At the moment I have read a lot of documentation and watched many video tutorials but I have not yet understood how to start customizing pages and components: the documentation is unclear and other resources found are often out of date.

How can I understand from the CMS which is the Home page? And what are the components that build it? How can I customize them?
Can anyone tell me what is the best approach to start customizing the header, footer and content based on the sketches I need to replicate? Where do I find a step by step guide that helps me do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S. Locally I have a default B2C multisite installation (Appareal and Electronics) with our backend as baseSite.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the Spartacus courses SAP is giving, it will give you a good start on how to work with the CMS. They are free and hold value for beginners.

Using the CmsService you can get the currentPage and based on the UID you can determine if you are on the homepage.

You can override components by creating Angular components and creating an override based on the class or flexType https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/

If you are new to Angular I really recommend doing a deep-dive on this first otherwise Spartacus will be very confusing. Been there...